# ListView: when move up the finger after long clicking an imageview in each row, the onItemClick function was called

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a problem about ListView.  First of all, this problem only occurs on my real Android device, it works ok on the simulator.

1 I have a ListView: listVew.  In each row of it, there's an imageView: picView.  I set a long click listener to the image view, in the customized Adapter:

```
picView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
{
   public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
   {
        ...
   }
}
```

When I long click the imageView, it'll move.

2 In my Activity class, I set OnItemClick Listener on every item of the listView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is, in the real device, when I long click the imageView and move up my finger, the OnItemClick method was activate.  In the simulator, this never occurred.

Does anyone know why this happened?  Thanks a lot!

Add:

I test in emulator for more times, now I think the question can be easy described like this now:

Is there a way to disable other TouchEvent listener when device detect a longclicklistener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to intercept the touch event of listview. So try to set OnClickListener in Adapter.getView()

```
View getView(View convertView, int position, ViewGroup parent){
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            onItemClick(parent, convertView, position, 0);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  You give me a big help.